# Connecting to SQL Server with SQuirrel SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I am in the process of learning more about database manipulation. I downloaded SQuirrel since it seemed like a good place to start.  I know quite a bit about SQL and databases already due to an internship I had last summer but know absolutely NOTHING about networking so I am having a tough time getting a database set up and created.

I set up the JDBC driver and everything but when it comes down to creating an Alias I am having a hard time figuring out where to go.  So far I have:

jdbc:sqlserver\localhost; create=true

for the URL but I keep getting SQL exceptions.  If there is anybody out there who has the patience and the ability to explain how to get started I would greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

`create` is not a valid connection property. The valid properties are here: [SQL Server JDBC connection properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx).

You should also include `databaseName` and `instanceName` in your JDBC connection url.